# Angular 2 Make an observable return inside a timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to make a method that retries HTTP calls a set number of times before giving up on the request and throwing an error. Everything is working fine if I just make one attempt after the next however we'd like to wait 1 second before making the final attempt.

How do I make an observable call another observable once a set timeout has elapsed?

Make a get request, if the request errors then catch the error and pass it to the handleError method.

```
private makeGetRequest ( address: string, callback: any, instance: any, cantRetry: boolean, timesRetried: boolean ): Observable<any> {
  return instance.http.get(address, instance.authHeaderService.getHeaders(address))
    .map(callback)
    .catch(( error: any ) => instance.handleError('get', error, address, cantRetry, timesRetried, callback));
}
```

If the request can be retryed then call the retryRequest method

```
private handleError ( type: string, error: any, address: string, cantRetry?: boolean, timesRetried?: number, callback?: any ): Observable<any> {
  if (!cantRetry) {
    return this.retryRequest(type, error, address, cantRetry, timesRetried, callback);
  }
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

If the error is repeatable and the status matches a retriable error and the request hasn't been retried the maximum number of times then wait for a timeout to elapse and then call the observable method this.makeRequest. However I get an error that a return statement is required. If I try to add the return in front of the timeout it says type number can't be converted to Observable. I also tried wrapping the timeout inside `Observable.create((observer: any) => { ... }` and then calling the makeRequest method from inside the `Observer.next()` method but it just returns an Observable method instead of calling the method.

```
private retryRequest(type: string, error: any, address: string, cantRetry: boolean, timesRetried: number, callback: any): Observable<any> {
  let retriableErrors: any[] = [ {
    maxRetries: 3,
    status: 500
  }, {
    maxRetries: 3,
    status: 504
  } ];
  let findError: any = ( retriableError: any ) => {
    return error.status = retriableError.status;
  };
  let retriableError: any = retriableErrors.find(findError);
  let timeoutLength: number = timesRetried === retriableError.maxRetries ? 1000 : 0;
  if (error.status === retriableError.status && !cantRetry && timesRetried <= retriableError.maxRetries) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      timesRetried++;
      console.log('Retrying request. Attempt ' + timesRetried + ' of ' + retriableError.maxRetries);
      return this.makeRequest(address, callback, this.requestFactory(type), cantRetry, timesRetried).subscribe();
    }, timeoutLength);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `retry` and `delay` operators? There is a possibility that you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'd follow @estus advice and use one of those suggested Operators. Anyway, if you want to implement this by yourself, the error tells correctly what's wrong. Instead of calling `setTimeout` yourself use `Observable.timer()` to schedule events and you can return Observable as expected. Btw, it's recommended to use already existing operators to implement your own operators.